# Notepad with instant search in files

Tags: search, notepad++, notepad

I'm looking for a Notepad replacement that could instantly search in opened files.
I mean something like searching in Evernote notes (start typing and then my list of files updates to only files which contain the typed phrase).

I have tried
Notepad2
Notepad++
Sublime Text
and few others

but what I want is
I have about 20+ txt files with diffrent content and i would like to type

1. CTRL+F
2. start typing and below i see instant results based on
       opened files or files in directory opened in editor

so i can correct my search based on results i see below
i don't want to click search every time and than again CTRL+F and click search and ...

Comment: @pnuts - Actually, it is: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6060/software-recommendations-what-software-can-do-this#comment15508_6060

Comment: @Adwinx, please update your question as this is off topic and *may* get closed and see this post as it may help: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software

Comment: I thought notepadd++ does this - you've included it as a tag, but have not explained why it isn't right for you.

Answer (score 1):

couldn’t you just use grep?

grep -r "search string"
do this command in the directory of your text files. This will return the name of the file, and highlight the given search parameter

Comment: yes but i want something faster, instant search, i want to see results as I type